# Two different definitions for a Complete Relation

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Many sources show this definition for completeness of a relation
$$
\forall a, b \in A, a \neq b, (aRb) \text{ or } (bRa) \tag{1}
$$ 
Others show only
$$
\forall a, b \in A, (aRb) \text{ or } (bRa) \tag{2}
$$

My question, assuming that the first definition is correct, why does the definition of a complete relation include the $a \neq b$ in its definition?
My doubt is that when given a relation and asked whether it is complete or not, which definition should I use (1) or (2) as given in the question. And why should I use that definition? 
For example- Given a relation On RxR 
R={(x,y)| x is not equal to y}. Is this relation complete?
Now if I use definition (1), it is complete.
If I use definition (2), it is not complete. So which is the right answer and why?

Comment: My doubt in simple words is that when given a relation and asked whether it is complete or not, which definition should I use (1) or (2) as given in the question. And why should I use that definition? For example- Given a relation On RxR R={(x,y)| x is not equal to y}. Is this relation complete?
Now if I use definition (1), it is complete.
If I use definition (2), it is not complete. So which is the right answer and why?